# Send message to TabHost's Fragment from Activity

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` which contains a `Fragment` in it. The `Fragment` contains a `TabHost` which contains several other `Fragments`. I need to send a message from `Activity` to one of `TabHost`s `Fragment`, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Really the only thing you can Fragment.getActivity() and then just walk down your fragment tree. (Activity.getTopFrag())

Comment: I think it might be easier to send your message with broadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the Observer-pattern implement an Observer interface in your activity, then you can register your fragment as an Observable. Now if you want to sent data to the activity you can use **notifyObserver**(object dataYouWantToSend) and call **hasChanged**().
This should be recognized by your activity where the interface method **update** will receive the data.

I recommend to create a custom observable object there you can override the notifyChange method and directly add the hasChanged() method. The overwritten method would look like this.

```
notifyChange(Object data) {
  super.notifyObservers(data);
  setChanged();
}
```